# firebase error on angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to add firebase to an angular 6 project.

`npm install firebase angularfire2 --save`

This project is based on ngx-admin, with some modification. I am a noob coming to angular and typescript.

After running the above-mentioned command, trying   `ng serve` gives me

> ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts(4,10): error TS2305:
>   Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'User'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts(4,16): error TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'auth'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,10): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'app'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,15): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'auth'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,21): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'database'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,31): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'firestore'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'functions'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,53): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'messaging'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,64): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"/Users/arash/Src/dance-admin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has
>   no exported member 'storage'.

```

I am very puzzled here, as the errors are coming from inside angularfire2, and not my project.
What is more puzzling is that, if I do the same thing with a brand new ng application, it just work fine.

So I guess the real question is, what these error messages mean? As the imports in the angularfire2 is clearly correct - at least at some setups.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the last update broke something. There is listed a breaking change [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases). Until a solution has been posted, you can use an older version of angularfire2. The release candidate 9 seems to work fine. Simply edit your package.json and replace the line

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10" // Gets the newest version
```

with

```
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9" // Gets a specific version
```

Comment: Older didn't work for another problem with the firebase. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387

Comment: This is best solution for me, thank`s guy.
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4", and  "firebase": "4.8.0",

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. made sure the versions in package.json were:

> ```
> angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9",
> "firebase": "5.0.2",
> ```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.